# Canadian inter-tribal wars

Tags: war, native-americans, canada

My research on Canadian Indian conflicts in the 19th century suggests that conflict between tribes was more severe than with the Europeans (expect for the second Metis rebellion). In particular, the conflicts between the Blackfoot and Cree tribes were especially large scale, with the last major battle occurring at Belly River in 1870.

Another notable battle occurred at Cypress Hills in 1867, in which a mixed group of Crows and other Native American groups were surprised by Blackfoot, resulting in a massacre.

Are these battle sites open to the public for those interested in touring battle fields? Or are these locations all now on private property?

Comment: I see two completely different questions asked in here. Which one is this question about?

Comment: The questions relating to the sites themselves may be more on-topic for [travel.se], but are not historical questions.

Answer (score 1):

A little googling leads to the [Battle of the Belly River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Belly_River) entry.  At the end of the discussion on this battle it states:

> In 1890, the town of Lethbridge was founded near the battle site. The
>   battle itself is commemorated in [Indian Battle Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Battle_Park).

More information can be found at the [City of Lethbridge](https://web.archive.org/web/20040828085321/http://www.lethbridge.ca/home/City+Hall/Departments/Parks+-+Pathways+-+Trails/Major+Parks/Indian+Battle+Park/Indian+Battle+Park.htm) website:

> Much of the battle took place in Indian Battle Coulee on the west
>   side of the river, while the retreat across the river ended in a last
>   stand close to the Coal Banks Interpretive Site.

So the city apparently has markers at least recognizing sites concerning the battle.

---

The [Cypress Hills Massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cypress_Hills_Massacre) website has the following concerning the site:

> The site of the massacre was designated a National Historic Site of
>   Canada in 1964.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Battle_Park) Artifacts from the Cypress Hills Massacre have also
>   been preserved at nearby [Fort Walsh National Historic Site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_Walsh), along with
>   reconstructions of Farwell's and Solomon's trading posts.